# Display Javascript Object In WebPage Without Knowing Its structure

Tags: javascript, html, console, javascript-objects

I want to Display javascript `document` object in webpage, in the same way it is displayed in console as object opening as dropdown. Is there any way by which we can display a javascript object on webpage without knowing its structure in the same way as console does?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for(var prop in document)
            document.write(prop + ' = ' + document[prop] + '<br>');
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```